# Magento website migrated to MAMP localhost. However homepage is working but links are not.

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, url, e-commerce

I downloaded a Magento website from a server and downloaded the database too. I followed some instructions to get the database working. I was required to change app/etc/local.xml and the base_url in the database.

[See base_url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzzQ3.png)

When I load the base_url address in the browser I get my website;

[See website homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmzJB.png)

If I take **public_html** out of the base_url and just load **localhost** the styles don't work at all. So I guess I need **public_html** in the base_url

My problem is that whenever I click a link, I get a 404 error - this is the url **localhost/public_html/mens/tees**

I read some stack overflow posts about .htaccess file, but I'm not entirely sure how to configure it to work for me?

[.htaccess file here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLj4Q.png)

Any help would be welcome. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

remove 'public_html' from your base_url database setting.

it should be

```
http://localhost/
```

your htaccess has:

```
RewriteBase /
```

this means apache is expecting no folder in the base url.

## alternatively

if you want to have public_html in the url for some reason, just change your htaccess to:

```
RewriteBase /public_html/
```